# How to send form data as a single JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, form-submit

Below is my code(client) to send form data in JSON format via JQUERY Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contextroot = "/services/"
    $("#customerForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var action = form.attr("action");
        var data = form.serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
                    url: contextroot+action,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("DATA POSTED SUCCESSFULLY"+data);
                    },
                    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        console.log( errorThrown );
                    }
        });
});
});
```

Below is the SPRING controller(service) to accept JSON data

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public CustomerDTO create(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        return customerService.create(customerDTO);
    }
```

On submitting the form, I get the following error
**HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.**

I guess this error is because the form data is serialized as array of JSON objects instead of just JSON object in request body as shown below

**[{"name":"firstName","value":"John"},{"name":"lastName","value":"Miller"},{"name":"email","value":"John@gmail.com"},{"name":"mobile","value":"99868377"}]**

However, service only accepts the following JSON data
**{
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName"  : "Miller",
  "email"     : "John.kp@gmail.com",
  "mobile"    : "99868377" 
}**

How to convert form data into a single **JSON object** instead of an **array of JSON objects**.

Comment: You can accept a `List<CustomerDTO>` in your controller method. Or you can use the `$.serialize` function instead of `$.serializeArray()`. 
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: You can accept a `List<CustomerDTO>` in your controller method. Or you can send data[0], if you are sure that you would have only one object in your JSON array.

Comment: $.serialize function will not parse form data into JSON

Comment: @Kartik right. Please refer to the second comment

Comment: Sure. I will try that. thanks

Comment: data[0] will not work as it returns only {"name":"firstName","value":"John"}.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I have written an utility method which generates JSON object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contextroot = "/services/"
    $("#customerForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var action = form.attr("action");
        var data = form.serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
                    url: contextroot+action,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(getFormData(data)),
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("DATA POSTED SUCCESSFULLY"+data);
                    },
                    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        console.log( errorThrown );
                    }
        });
});
});

//utility function
function getFormData(data) {
   var unindexed_array = data;
   var indexed_array = {};

   $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i) {
    indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
   });

   return indexed_array;
}
```